# remove duplicates based on column in inner join

Tags: sql-server, join, duplicates

This is returning exactly what I want, except some rows need to be removed because the inner join has matched multiple rows when I only want it to match the first match.

```
select table1.IDa, table1.IDb, table1.name,
       table1b.IDa, table1b.IDb, table1b.name  
from

(select IDa,IDb,name from mytable) table1 

inner join 

(select IDa,IDb,name from mytable) table1b 

ON  

table1.IDa = table1b.IDa 
and table1.IDb = table1b.IDb 

order By table1.IDa
```

So I'm getting this:

```
IDa     IDb     name   IDa     IDb     name
1       1       bob    1       1       public
1       1       bob    1       1       smith
1       2       sally  1       2       jones
2       1       nancy  2       1       dole
```

But I want to receive this:

```
IDa     IDb     name   IDa     IDb     name
1       1       bob    1       1       public
1       2       sally  1       2       jones
2       1       nancy  2       1       dole
```

I only want the first match for the IDa+IDb combination returned.

Comment: Can you define **"first match"**. I mean why `public` is selected over `smith`

Comment: @Fireblade That would be the oldest entry into the database, it would also be the same as order by IDa,IDb.  It would also be the first match seen in the returned results.

Comment: @TechGuy DISTINCT doesn't work because that looks at an entire row, not just 1 column.  There are no 2 identical rows in my example above.

Answer (score 0):

Based on asker's comment

> That would be the oldest entry into the database, it would also be the
>   same as order by IDa,IDb. It would also be the first match seen in the
>   returned results

Try this query :

```
select table1.IDa, table1.IDb, table1.name,
       table1b.IDa, table1b.IDb, table1b.name  
from

(select IDa,IDb,name from mytable) table1 

inner join 

(select IDa,IDb,name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY Ida,IDb) as r from mytable ) table1b 

ON  

table1.IDa = table1b.IDa 
and table1.IDb = table1b.IDb 
and table1b.r=1

order By table1.IDa
```

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but that doesn't return any rows.  No errors. No rows.

Comment: I think what I need instead of using ROW NUMBER is the "GROUP BY" function, but I have not been able to get the syntax correct on it.

Comment: are both tables same. then why did we not get a row like `1       1       bob 1       1       bob `

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments this should work, But `Smith` and `Public` has same `IDa` and `IDb` values hope it is data issue.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT rn=Row_number()OVER(partition BY table1b.name ORDER BY table1.IDa, table1.IDb),
                table1.IDa   AS t1_ida,
                table1.IDb   AS t1_idb,
                table1.name  AS t1_name,
                table1b.IDa  AS t2_ida,
                table1b.IDb  AS t2_idb,
                table1b.name AS t2_name
         FROM   mytable table1
                INNER JOIN mytable table1b
                        ON table1.IDa = table1b.IDa
                           AND table1.IDb = table1b.IDb)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn = 1
```